# Loop de redirecionamentos - Wordpress x Google Chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, redirecionamento

Algo estranho vem ocorrendo desde ontem em um site de um cliente http://terraencantadaonline.com.br/.

Em alguns PCs e somente usando o Google Chrome(IE, Firefox e Safari estão ok), ao tentar acessar o Site ele entra em Loop de redirecionamentos. Nada foi alterado a meses no htaccess, tampouco em qualquer código do sistema.

Entrei em contato com o host e nenhuma alteração na plataforma deles foi feita, ou seja, nada que justifique essa estranha reação do Chrome apontando redirecionamentos.

Alguém já passou por alguma situação parecida? Alguma ideia do que possa ser?

Comment: O seu site usa algum tipo de proxy/CDN? Ex: CloudFlare, MaxCDN
Eu tive um problema parecido quando configurei meus DNS no CloudFlare e o servidor de hospedagem não respondia.

Comment: Nenhum. Como disse antes o site não apresentava problema algum até quinta a noite. Reforço: Está ocorrendo somente no Google Chrome.

Comment: O problema ocorria por conta da versão atual do Chrome mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema ocorria por conta da versão menos recente do Google Chrome.

Caso mais alguém sofra com este problema, lembre-se de manter o navegador atualizado.